# Graphql server - Can't access via IP address url (localhost works fine)

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo

I would like to link my Expo(React Native) app to local GraphQL backend,

`http://localhost:4000/` <- Works fine

`http://192.168.X.X:4000/` <- This doesn't work

I do see the Apollo Studio page, but it comes up with the below message:

```
Unable to reach server

Network requests from Studio on HTTPS to your HTTP endpoint are not secure,
so we cannot introspect your endpoint.
```

`https://studio.apollographql.com/sandbox/explorer`

Answer (score 3):

Apollo Studio has a special exception that allows it to communicate with "localhost" over http, but all other endpoints must be over https.

If you (like me) are running virtual machines on your local machine and need to use Apollo Studio, the only solutions are to make the connection https somehow, or forward a port in your host OS so that you can access it via localhost. How to do THAT depends on your OS.